# Haven't achieved Electorate badge?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I wasn't too sure about this until I checked today and saw a breakdown of my votes cast on my profile.

The Electorate badge states: Voted on 600 questions and 25% or more of total votes are on questions

I've voted 639 times, 634 up votes, 5 down votes with 354 votes on questions and 285 votes on answers. I believe this is what the badge is asking for, unless I'm mistaken.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To earn the electorate badge, you must:

1) Vote on 600 questions
2) At least 25% of your total votes must be on questions.

You have over 600 total votes, but not over 600 votes on questions.

Comment: Thanks very much :)